# How to login as a PFUser/ParseUser when internet is unavailable?

Tags: parse-platform

Im trying to run my Login app offline.I initially enabled local datastore and then have retrieved users online and pinned them like this:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The find succeeded. The first 100 objects are available in objects

            [PFObject pinAllInBackground:objects];
            NSLog(@"%@", objects);
            PFUser *user =[objects objectAtIndex:1];

            NSLog(@"%@",user.username);
            NSLog(@"%@",user.password);
            NSLog(@"%@",user.email);
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure

            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
```

After That I tried to login without internet but PFLoginViewController shows the following error:

```
[Error]: The Internet connection appears to be offline. (Code: 100, Version: 1.7.1)
```